# Trying to understand tree structure composition in Cycle.js

Tags: javascript, cyclejs

I am currently learning Cycle.js through reading the official "docs" and any examples I can find. I am still working through some of the core concepts, and in particular have found myself stuck trying to understand how to form a top-level component.  I think it is because I'm still struggling with how to work effectively with streams...

In my scenario, utilizing xstream and snabbdom, I have a list of items that I want to render in a `ul>li` format.  I can see how my list translates to the `li` form:

```
const sampleItems$ = xs.fromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const liNodes$ = sampleItems$.map(item => li(item));
```

What I don't understand is how I can wrap the `liNodes$` inside a `ul` without mutating an existing node, e.g.

```
const ulNode$ = liNodes$.fold((ul, li) => {
    ul.children.push(li);
    return ul;
}, ul([]));
```

I assume the above example is not the correct way to "nest" stream content within a container.  I realize this could probably be provided by static markup, but would like to understand how to compose this structure with stream operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
const sampleItems$ = xs.fromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

The result is a stream that emits the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, over time. On the other hand, if you write

```
const sampleItems$ = xs.of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

The result is a stream that emits **one value**, and that value is the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. This is probably what you want, because then you are able to do

```
const ulNode$ = sampleItems$.map(sampleItems =>
  ul(sampleItems.map(item =>
    li(item)
  )
);
```